# How to create a custom templatetag in my django project

Tags: python, django

I have been trying create a custom templatetag in my project , but it does not work

This is my structured project :

I created a folder in my index directory called templatetags > `__init__.py , extras.py` , inside extras file this:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
def cut(value):
   return value.replace("no", 'yes')
```

**Template** : {% load poll_extras %}

but I  got this

[image: Error]

Comment: You need to add it to an *app*, and add that app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created a folder in my index directory called `templatetags` > `__init__.py` , `extras.py` , inside extras file this.

You should add this to an app. So in the root directory, you have the directory of the app, and under that app directory you create a `templatetags` directory.

```
app_name  # ← name of the app
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        extra.py
```

This app should be an installed app, so you add the name of the app in the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

```
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APP = [
    # …,
    'app_name',
    # …,
]
```

You furthermore need to *register* the template tag:

```
# app_name/templatetags/extra.py

from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.tag  # ← register the template tag
def cut(value):
   return value.replace("no", 'yes')
```

You should use `@register.filter` in case you want to register a *template filter*, instead of a *template tag*.